# simpleinjector singleton property

Tags: c#, uwp, simple-injector

With simple injector is there a way to set a property or have a constructor parameter that is not an interface?

My application is a UWP WebVew and most of the services are dependent on it and its state.

I created a wrapper for it so that I could inject it into all of the services like this:

```
public interface IWebBrowser
{
    WebView WebView { get; set; }
}

public class WebBrowser : IWebBrowser
{
    public WebView WebView { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var Container = new Container();
        Container.Register<IWebBrowser, WebBrowser>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        Container.Register<MainViewModel>();

        var web = Container.GetInstance<IWebBrowser>();
        web.WebView = WebView;

        Vm = Container.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly web;

    public MainViewModel(IWebBrowser web)
    {
        this.web = web;
    }
}
```

This works but it looks error prone.  Is there a way to do this without these two lines:

```
var web = Container.GetInstance<IWebBrowser>();
web.WebView = WebView;
```

Comment: The container is something you would want to be created once when the applications starts not something you would create each time a page loads.
Something like this: https://github.com/shawn42/xamarin-web-sample/blob/011d46068c2fce8b3373b57cb78a1078219bb32d/XamarinWebSample/XamarinWebSample/App.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`RegisterInitializer`](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_RegisterInitializer__1.htm) which is a little more robust

> Registers an `Action<T>` delegate that runs after the creation of
>   instances that implement or derive from the given TService. Please
>   note that only instances that are created by the container (using
>   constructor injection) can be initialized this way

```
container.RegisterInitializer<IWebBrowser>(x => o.WebView = WebView);
```

<sub>***Note*** : Though i am a little confused at what `WebView` is and why it needs to be poked in anyway.</sub>

Comment: WebView is the name of the control. I'm automating a browser to run tasks on a schedule.  It needs to use a browser because the REST API is limited.

Comment: @Adam Seems like its always needed and non changing, why not just DI that into your concrete *WebBrowser* class

Comment: Is it possible to do that? Everything needs to reference the control on the form.  I'm just doing it this way to provide a degree of abstraction so that the same code could work with a different webview control.